# How to make MarkerClusters use panes

Tags: javascript, leaflet, z-index, leaflet.markercluster, panes

Let's say we have the following map:

https://jsfiddle.net/fcumj09w/5/

In the above example, we have 2 marker cluster groups (clustRed and clustYellow) and a single marker outside of these groups.

I want the red marker cluster group to be on top (higher z-index) of the yellow marker cluster group, when zooming out.

I have created 3 custom panes to attach each cluster group to a different pane but it seems like panes don't work with cluster groups (or I haven't find the way to make them work).

What I tried:

```
var clustRed = L.markerClusterGroup({pane:'hilevel'});
var clustYellow = L.markerClusterGroup({pane:'lowlevel'});
```

I can only make panes work with the single marker:

```
L.circleMarker([45,5],{pane:"midlevel"}).addTo(map);
```

How can I make Leaflet.markercluster use the `pane` that I specify?

Comment: If you look at the dom, your two markercluster layers are in the `marker` pane. More precisely, they are in a `<div>` with the class `leaflet-marker-pane`. Your single marker is well placed in the `midlevel` pane. I think L.markercluster does not transmit the `pane` option to the layer(s) it creates.

Comment: Thank you Julien. Seems like a markerCluster plugin issue, then..

Comment: I found a solution with "!important" in .css but it isn't the way I would like to solve my problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** this functionality is [now available](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#110-2017-08-27) as [`clusterPane`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#other-options) option. Added since version [1.1.0](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/releases/tag/v1.1.0).

```
var clustRed = L.markerClusterGroup({clusterPane: 'hilevel'});
```

---

Although [Layer Groups](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup) in Leaflet (including the MarkerClusterGroup from [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) plugin) inherit from the [`Layer`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layer) base class, which indeed provide the [`pane`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layer-pane) option, any child layer added to them still use their own specified `pane`, if any, or use the default one (i.e. `overlayPane`).

It is still undecided whether that behaviour should be changed or not (see [Leaflet issue #4279](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4279)).

In the case of a MarkerClusterGroup, the latter even actually *generates* markers on its own, using the `L.MarkerCluster` class, which represent a cluster of individual markers.

From your description, you would like those generated markers to be inserted in specific panes.

In that case, you could very simply override the [`initialize`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/v1.0.5/src/MarkerCluster.js#L2-L24) method of `L.MarkerCluster` class so that it uses whichever `pane` you want. In your case, you would read the MarkerClusterGroup' option `pane` member:

```js
L.MarkerCluster.include({
  initialize: function(group, zoom, a, b) {

    var latLng = a ? (a._cLatLng || a.getLatLng()) : new L.LatLng(0, 0),
      options = {
        icon: this
      },
      pane = group.options.pane; // Read the MarkerClusterGroup's pane, if any.

    // If a pane is specified, add it to the MarkerCluster's options.
    if (pane) {
      options.pane = pane;
    }

    L.Marker.prototype.initialize.call(this, latLng, options);

    // Remaining code is unchanged compared to original method.
    this._group = group;
    this._zoom = zoom;
    this._markers = [];
    this._childClusters = [];
    this._childCount = 0;
    this._iconNeedsUpdate = true;
    this._boundsNeedUpdate = true;
    this._bounds = new L.LatLngBounds();
    if (a) {
      this._addChild(a);
    }
    if (b) {
      this._addChild(b);
    }
  }
});
```

Once this is patched, the generated marker clusters will use the `pane` that you specify when instantiating the MarkerClusterGroup, as shown in your question:

```js
var clustRed = L.markerClusterGroup({pane:'hilevel'});
var clustYellow = L.markerClusterGroup({pane:'lowlevel'});
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fcumj09w/9/

Comment: And notice that the option name is `clusterPane`, not `clustersPane` that some of the pre-1.1.0 version proof of concept examples that you can find when searching use...